# My auto-buying code for BestBuy isn't working... why?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, best-buy-api

I've been trying to get this code to work, but it just won't. (The link is a placeholder, I'm planning on changing it to a 3060 Ti to get one for a home rig.) It also says the goToCartBtn was clicked, but it wasn't.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
#For using chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver')

#BestBuy RTX 3060 Ti webpage
browser.get('https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nvidia-geforce-rtx-nvlink-bridge-for-3090-cards-space-gray/6441554.p?skuId=6441554')


buyButton = False 

while not buyButton:
try:
    #If this works, then the button is not pytopen
    addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-disabled")

    #Button isn't open, restart the script
    print("Button isn't ready yet.")

    #Refresh page after a delay
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.refresh()

except:

    addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-primary")

    #Click the button 
    print("Button was clicked.")
    addToCartBtn.click()
    
    goToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-secondary")

    print("Go To Cart button was clicked.")
    goToCartBtn.click()

    checkoutBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-lg")

    print("Checkout button clicked.")
    checkoutBtn.click()
    buyButton = True
```

Error Message shown below:

```
Terminal Logs (if needed):
Button was clicked.
Go To Cart button was clicked.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SniperBot.py", line 15, in <module>
    addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-disabled")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn-disabled"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SniperBot.py", line 35, in <module>
    goToCartBtn.click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)
```

Comment: Why is there an = addbutton in the middle of each line?

Comment: I followed a tutorial and assumed there had to be an addbutton every time. (The tutorial only showed the first part, I did the rest) Should I remove those?

Comment: Yeah they don't do anything.

Comment: Couple of aside notes about the code - you can shorthand the clicking actions in one line by doing `browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn-primary').click()`. and I would put the `print` statements *after* the click functions, rather than before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goToCartButton selector is not specific enough.

```
 goToCartButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn-secondary')
```

Using this selector returns *five* elements, and Selenium will only interact with the first one it finds, which according to the DOM, isn't the "Go to Cart" button.

Instead, you could use a CSS selector to return the specific element. Using CSS:

```
goToCartButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.go-to-cart-button .btn-secondary')
```

And you should be able to click the button now.

Comment: Another problem you might run into is that the selectors are right, but they are going to fast for the browser. Ideally, it's a good idea to add an **implicit wait** so that it can wait for an element to be found or a command to complete. To do this, just put `browser.implicitly_wait(10)` (10 being the number of seconds to wait) right under the line where `browser` was defined.

Comment: I'd suggest swapping over to webdriver waits. Massive improvement in time than using implicit.

Comment: explicit waits are fine too -- I just prefer to use implicit wait in this case since given the size and scope of the code, it's not all too complicated

Comment: New Code failed.
goToCartBtn = browser.find_element_by_class_name(".go-to-cart-button .btn-secondary")

        time.sleep(5)
        print("Go To Cart button was clicked.")
        goToCartBtn.click()

Comment: @TVXD the code should be `find_element_by_css_selector` not `find_element_by_class_name`

Comment: still doesn't work, now the terminal logs are too long for me to post (somehow the fix made the logs longer?) EDIT: WAIT NEVERMIND IT WORKED BY ADDING A DELAY!
TYSM, MY BRAIN CAN FINALLY REST

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "go to cart" button, only a URL "bestbuy.com/cart", I use that for my bot.